# New to ubuntu, not sure what to call this but please help

Tags: boot

I recently switched to Ubuntu and this is the second time I have faced this problem. The first time I reinstalled ubuntu and it was fine, because at the time I hardly had anything of value downloaded. Now however, I'm reluctant to giving up and reinstalling, is there anything I can do?
Greater effort: usually when I turn on my computer after a power off it goes to  login screen, no problems. Here it stays on this screen frozen. I am unable to do anything other than turning it off, before I get to this screen however I can access the BIOS, not sure if that's something of importance here.

I am using an Intel NUC if that helps

Thanks!
-grateful noob

Was going to add a picture but you need 10 reputation so that's nice, here's the link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/71jL9.jpg

Comment: Please, could you take a picture of the bottommost lines of the picture? Is very important to use a good title for your question, so we can know at least what seems to fail,  and we would appreciate very much a greater effort in describing the issue (i.e. the computer freezes at boot). Also, ¡welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: The picture shows a Linux system booting normally. What is the actual problem that you are having?

Comment: Did you change your graphics driver away from default nouveau ? possibly install Nvidia drivers ?

Comment: Depending on version, a NUC may work better with some minor driver changes or boot parameters. Certified ISO & Instructions
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-nuc-desktop
intel nuc - nuc5i5MYHE w/M.2 SSD 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376245  Have you updated UEFI/BIOS for your NUC. Many systems work better with updates to UEFI.